# Setting Sql Dependency with ICacheClient

Tags: c#, memcached, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack for caching purpose in an ASP.NET MVC4 API project. Now I need to set a sql dependency for it.

1. Is there a way to set SQL dependency `ICacheClient`?
2. I thought of doing it by generating unique string from post parameters. Is there a way to generate unique string from post parameters or query string parameters?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? Are you tracking changes in the DB via triggers?

Comment: yes sql server 2008 and no trigger used

Comment: How do you track DB changes for the SQL dependency?

Comment: hey that is only my actual question. How to track it?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to enable change tracking in your database.

The microsoft way of doing this would be to use the aspnet_regsql tool to 'enable' cache dependency on one or many of your database tables.

> aspnet_regsql -S localhost -E -d yourdatabase -ed  //enable database
>   for cache
>
> aspnet_regsql -S localhost -E -d yourdatabase -et -t yourtable //
>   enabling table for cache

This creates update,insert,delete triggers on the table that increment a counter in another table it creates.
So when you i.e run an update on Users table the corresponding row in the cache table will have its counter incremented.

Now you need to hook into this new table from your ServiceStack layer.

One way would be to query the table every X seconds (it will be a quick query as there will only be as many rows as there are enabled tables). The returned data may look like:

```
TABLE    CHANGE_COUNT
Users    13
Tags     432
```

Using the data returned you can construct generational cache keys. If/when the change count increments it will mean the next time you get your cache key the number in it will have changed, therefor psuedo-invalidating the cache.